# inputProps={{ readOnly: true }} doesn't work for Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, material-ui

I am trying to implement a material ui autocomplete with readOnly set as True. I have understood from various forums that inputProps attribute overrides the InputProps parameter of params. However, I tried the workaround suggested and that fails too. Find below the code snippet below.

```
<Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="listvalues"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="filterSelectedOptions"
            placeholder="Favorites",
            inputProps={{...params.inputProps, readOnly: true }}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `readOnly: true`? I put your example into https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions65993841-n0h14?file=/src/App.js and it seems to work as expected -- I cannot directly add text to the box, I can only add things to the Autocomplete by selecting items in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

inputProps is different from InputProps

```
InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, readOnly: true, }}
```

Answer (score 1):

inputProps={{ readOnly: true }} Only impacts text input and has no effect on the Autocomplete component recommendations in a Material UI. You may use the disabled prop on the Autocomplete component itself to deactivate it.